# Deleting orphans with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, named-query

I have a one-to-one relation where I use CascadeType.PERSIST. This has over time build up a huge amount of child records that has not been deleted, to such an extend that it is reflected in the performance.
Now I wish to add some code that cleans up the database removing all the child records that are not referenced by a parent. At the moment we are talking 400K+ records, at I need to run the code on all customer installations just to be sure they do not run into the same problem.

I think the best solution would be to run a named query (because we support two databases) that deletes the necessary records, and this is where I get into problems, because how should I write it in JPQL?

The result I want can be defined like the following sql statement, which unfortunaltely does not run on MySQL.

```
DELETE FROM child c1
WHERE c1.pk NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.pk FROM child c2
JOIN parent p ON p.child = c2.pk);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM child c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM parent WHERE child = c.pk)
```